# Modify closure in PHP

Tags: php, closures

Is possible to modify (add more code) to a closure in PHP after is passed to a parameter?

```
function foo () {
    bar (
        function () {
             $a = baz ();
             $b = fooBar ();
        }
    );
}
function bar (Closure $closure) {
    $closure // <------ I need to add code to this function.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can not add or modify a closure, but you can create another closure which calls this closure:

```
public function getClosure() {
    $closure = getOtherClosure();
    return function() use ($closure) {
        //Do other things
        $closure();
    };
}
```